# spark java.util.logging.Logger

Tags: logging, apache-spark

I am using Spark to run an existing Java package which uses `java.util.logging.Logger`, and I am getting an error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:911)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:910)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:910)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:46)
    at edu.uth.clamp.nlp.main.RunPipelineWithSpark.processFolder(RunPipelineWithSpark.java:271)
    at edu.uth.clamp.nlp.main.RunPipelineWithSpark.process(RunPipelineWithSpark.java:179)
    at edu.uth.clamp.nlp.main.RunPipelineWithSpark.main(RunPipelineWithSpark.java:136)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.logging.Logger
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: java.util.logging.Logger, value: java.util.logging.Logger@a23dc07)
    - field (class: edu.uth.clamp.nlp.ner.CRFNameEntityRecognizer, name: logger, type: class java.util.logging.Logger)
    - object (class edu.uth.clamp.nlp.ner.CRFNameEntityRecognizer, edu.uth.clamp.nlp.ner.CRFNameEntityRecognizer@5199fdf9)
    - field (class: edu.uth.clamp.nlp.uima.NameEntityUIMA, name: recognizer, type: class edu.uth.clamp.nlp.ner.CRFNameEntityRecognizer)
    - object (class edu.uth.clamp.nlp.uima.NameEntityUIMA, edu.uth.clamp.nlp.uima.NameEntityUIMA@23a84ec4)
    - writeObject data (class: java.util.ArrayList)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check you are trying to serialize logger instance, make the logger field as static or transient.

Answer (score 1):

Spark expects the function that is passed inside the transformation of rdd/dstream should be serializable. Since the java.util.logging.Logger is not serializable , you should not have logging related code inside the function. You could replace the log with simple println . Or you could try the options suggested here.

[Apache Spark logging within Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208844/apache-spark-logging-within-scala)

Note that log can be there in driver code.
 And make sure that it is not referencing any variable outside your function which is not serializable. To have a better understanding on serialization due to closure, learn the concept of closure [doc](https://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2010/11/15/functional-scala-closures/) [doc2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636/what-is-a-closure).

Answer (score 1):

Try using @transient lazy val while creating the log object. Also it is better to use it inside closure so that spark itself will take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code probably looks something like

```
NameEntityUIMA nameEntity = ...;
JavaRDD<SomeType> rdd = ...;
rdd.foreach(x -> /* code using nameEntity */);
```

`foreach` has to serialize its argument to send it to each node; because the argument uses `nameEntity`, it needs to be serialized too, but it can't be (and due to the design of Java serialization, this is only detected at runtime instead of giving a compilation error). Instead, you want to create the `nameEntity` on each partition. You could do

```
JavaRDD<SomeType> rdd = ...;
rdd.foreach(x -> {
    NameEntityUIMA nameEntity = ...;
    /* code using nameEntity */
});
```

but this creates a new `nameEntity` for each element of the RDD, which would perform horribly. Instead, use [`foreachPartition`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike.html#foreachPartition(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction)).

Answer (score 0):

Logger is not serializable and most likely you are trying to access it from executors. I would suggest to have it defined as lazy

```
lazy val logger = ....
```

However the drawback is that you shouldn't be using the logger within driver. The other option that is not very sexy is that have another logger for the executors..