# How to use org.slf4j.Logger in spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, slf4j

I'm trying to use `org.slf4j.Logger` in spark. If I write as follows, I will get the error that `non-static field cannot be referenced from a static context`. Because the method `main` is static but `logger` is non-static.

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class simpleApp {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String logFile = "/user/beibei/zhaokai/spark_java/a.txt"; // Should be some file on your system
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaRDD<String> logData = sc.textFile(logFile).cache();

        logger.info("loading graph from cache");

        long numAs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean call(String s) { return s.contains("a"); }
        }).count();

        long numBs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean call(String s) { return s.contains("t"); }
        }).count();

        System.out.println("Lines with a: " + numAs + ", lines with t: " + numBs);
    }
}
```

However, if I write like follows. I will get another

> error Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task
>   not serializable.

Because the Object of Class simpleApp is not serializable.

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class simpleApp {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new simpleApp().start();
    }

    private void start() {
        String logFile = "/path/a.txt"; // Should be some file on your system
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaRDD<String> logData = sc.textFile(logFile).cache();

        logger.info("loading graph from cache");

        long numAs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean call(String s) { return s.contains("a"); }
        }).count();

        long numBs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean call(String s) { return s.contains("t"); }
        }).count();

        System.out.println("Lines with a: " + numAs + ", lines with t: " + numBs);
    }
}
```

So what am I supposed to do?
If I want to use some other packages like `org.slf4j.Logger`, will I meet the same problem?

Comment: And how about making ``logger`` a static member of class ``simpleApp``? e.g ``LoggerFactory.getLogger(simpleApp.class)``?

Answer (score -1):

There might be several options available.... I'd offer [org.apache.spark.internal.Logging](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5f11e8c4cb9a5db037ac239b8fcc97f3a746e772/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/internal/Logging.scala) provided by spark(>=2.2 version of spark).

**Doc says :**

```
/**
 * Utility trait for classes that want to log data. Creates a SLF4J logger for the class and allows
 * logging messages at different levels using methods that only evaluate parameters lazily if the
 * log level is enabled.
 */
```

---

```
private def isLog4j12(): Boolean = {
// This distinguishes the log4j 1.2 binding, currently
// org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory, from the log4j 2.0 binding, currently
// org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory
val binderClass = StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton.getLoggerFactoryClassStr
"org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory".equals(binderClass)
 }
```

If you want to do same thing on your own with out using spark provided api, you can mimic the same.

> Note : In the above approach..  To adjust logging level use
>   sc.setLogLevel(newLevel).  For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).

Also have a look at : [apache-spark-logging-within-scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208844/apache-spark-logging-within-scala)